A word problem I can't solve.
$24$ identical glasses are sitting on three trays. The first tray has eight glasses which are full. The second tray has eight glasses which are half-full. The third tray has eight glasses which are empty. Find all the ways of rearranging the glasses so that the weight on each of the three trays will be the same.
My working so far:
Let the weight of a full glass be $1$ unit, the weight of a half-full glass be $0.5$ units and the weight of an empty glass be $0$ units.
So the total weight is $12$ units $\left(8+4+0\right)$, and for each tray you would divide $12$ by $3$.
Next, I made a $3\times3$ grid




Full
Half
Empty




Tray $1$





Tray $2$





Tray $3$






and, each column must add up to $8$ and each row must add up to $4$ where you use the formula Full+$\frac{\text{Half}}2$.
That's as far as I got to.

Are the empty glasses supposed to be weightless?

the numbers only represent how full the glass is, not the glass itself, each glass is the same if you remove all liquid

But if the glasses are weightless, then there are more answers than if they aren't. If the weight of an empty glass is zero, then putting four full glasses on each of the first two trays and the rest on the last tray works, but if the glasses have weight then the last tray would be heavier.

Let's start from wherever you finished:




Full
Half
Empty




Tray 1





Tray 2





Tray 3






Consider tray 1 has $x_1$ and $y_1$ number of glasses that are full and empty. To make a total weight of $4$, there must be $8-2x_1$ number of glasses that are half filled. Similarly, it goes for the other three trays as well. The weight of empty glasses is not counted as it is zero:
Therefore, the number of glasses, considering that each column must contain $8$ of them is:




Full
Half
Empty




Tray 1
$x_1$
$8-2x_1$
$y_1$


Tray 2
$x_2$
$8-2x_2$
$y_2$


Tray 3
$8-(x_1+x_2)$
$2(x_1+x_2)-8$
$8-(y_1+y_2)$



Each column has $8$ glasses and each row has a weight of $4$. We need to put values from $0$ to $8$ in this, so that $(x_1+x_2)\geq4$ and $(x_1+x_2)\leq8$ and moreover, $(y_1+y_2)\leq 8$.
There are $35$ ways of arranging $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $45$ ways of arranging $y_1$ and $y_2$. Since the variable-pairs are independent of each other, it then makes a total of $1575$ ways of arranging the glasses.

isnt there 35 ways of arranging x1 + x2 and 45 for y1 + y2

Fixed it. Thanks.
